# Interfacing Gammon's RS485 with computer

Tags: rs485

I'm using the non-blocking RS485 Gammon's library for Arduino (as shown at http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11428) to handle the communication between some arduinos.
Now I'm having trouble to add a Raspberry Pi (or otherwise a non-arduino platform) to the network.

How can I integrate the Gammon's protocol in a python or processing software?

Comment: Surely the Pi supports the C++ language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open-source and Web-search is just great. [This](https://github.com/Sthing/Nick-Gammon-RS485) might be what you are looking for.

Cheers!